# How to find $k$ using the determinants matrices properties?

Tags: matrices, determinant

So lets say I want to find $k$ in this question:

$\det \begin{pmatrix}2a_1\:&\:2a_2&2a_3\:\\ 3b_1+5c1\:&3\:b_2+5c_2\:&\:3b_3+5c_3\:\\ 7c1\:&\:7c_2\:&\:7c_3\:\end{pmatrix}=k\cdot \det \:\begin{pmatrix}a_1\:&\:a_2&a_3\:\\ \:b_1\:&\:b_2\:&\:b_3\:\\ \:c1\:&\:c_2\:&\:c_3\:\end{pmatrix}$

Here is my attempt using the properties of determinant:

$\ = det \begin{pmatrix}2a_1\:&\:2a_2&2a_3\:\\ 3b_1\:&3\:b_2\:&\:3b_3\:\\ 7c1\:&\:7c_2\:&\:7c_3\:\end{pmatrix} + \det \begin{pmatrix}2a_1\:&\:2a_2&2a_3\:\\ 5c1\:&5c_2\:&\:5c_3\:\\ 7c1\:&\:7c_2\:&\:7c_3\:\end{pmatrix}$

Since two rows are the same, well, it is not really, but they are scalars multiple of one another so I can say that the determinant is zero right?

then

$\ = det \begin{pmatrix}2a_1\:&\:2a_2&2a_3\:\\ 3b_1\:&3\:b_2\:&\:3b_3\:\\ 7c1\:&\:7c_2\:&\:7c_3\:\end{pmatrix}$

This is where I am stuck, can I factor the $2$, $3$ and $7$ out? So is $k$ = $2 \times 3 \times  7?$ Exactly which rule is this?

Also what is the linearity of the determinant? Thanks - Sarah

Comment: You can view scaling a row or a column of a matrix as multiplying by an elementary matrix $E$. So the determinant is just $\det E \cdot \det A$.

Comment: @Soby  Thanks for the comment, but what is the $E$?

Comment: You have already used linearity of the determinant in your second part of the equation. Linearity simply states, that the determinant behaves linearly with respect to each row, while keeping the others fixed. Since the second row was a sum, you could write the determinant as the sum of two determinants. Now you can use linearity in each row again, factoring out the scalars 2,3 and 7, just as your intuition was.

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend Hello Sven thanks for the insightful answer! So I am correct? I can factor out the scalar multiple each time?

Comment: Yes, your approach is totally correct.